# Python Parse Binary Data to record file

Tags: python, binary

I have a code that reads a Binary file :

```
n = 820
with open('/home/drdos/work/PTSIBS01.PDA', "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(n)
        if not data:
            break

        filename = str(data[3:18])
        x = open(filename, 'wb').write(data)
```

but my problem is the File i'm trying to iterate and divide as you see on the c0de contain double slashes (" // ")on the name like this :

07112011142635//TS

and the program just runs 2 times and then after creating 2 files says :

```
drdos@poison:~/work$ python pybin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pybin.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = open(filename, 'wb').write(data)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '12011142635//PT'
```

Well in resume to give just a basic view my code exists to create a record file from this bit binary file and for each 820 bytes creates a file with that content of 820 bytes and a filename that is the exact copy of the string present in between the 3 byte and the 18 byte.

file type = File.Dat
i need to extract every record each record is =
1 record equals to :

```
Field  |     Format  |  name  | len    | description
1        array         NR_UP    2        //
2        array         Bla_N    16       ASCII coded i need for filename
3        Binary Array   Sig     256      content
4        Binary Array   Sig     270      content
5        Binary Array   SigA    256      content
6        Hash           Hash    20       Sha1
```

For each record like this i need a file :) and this for all the 20Mb of source (File.dat) but anyone wants to change my original code or have a better idea how to do this would be great.

Comment: Have a look at the [struct module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and `unpack_from`

Comment: You are extracting *15* characters from your byte chunks, btw, not 16. I would expect `data[2:18]` to be the second field in your data structure, not `data[3:18]`. This doesn't solve your problem, this is just an observation.

Comment: well i found the awnser i was looking on the wrong position it was not from the 3:18 was from 16:32 :D

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you know if its possible instead of looking for the 820 bytes limit look for the pattern // everytime i find the // i save a file with the bytes from one // to another that is the prefix that separate a record from another